# Android How to add TEXT to Share Dialog (fb sdk 3.5)

Tags: android, facebook

Android Facebook sdk 3.5 have just released with Native Share Dialog.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/
But it only can share the Link + Open graph.
Have anybody try to add Text with Link in Share Dialog.
Like this: 
https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/851578_156286967898481_1469422341_n.png 
With hint "What's in your mind" is some TEXT.
Thanks

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to pre-fill the message. The user has to type it in.

Comment: It mean no way to share a Link with TEXT :|

Comment: I understood what you meant. Facebook does not allow you to specify the TEXT, the user needs to explicitly type it in.